# PHP $_SERVER variable to identify file requested

Tags: php, webserver, apache2, global-variables

In the PHP $_SERVER variable, four variables reference the file requested.:

```
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>   string(21) "/webroot/file.php"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>       string(9) "/file.php?param=valyou"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>       string(9) "/file.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>          string(9) "/file.php"
```

Would/Could any of these array members not refer to the actual file requested via URL? For example, URL rewriting, which I don't have experience with or plan on using for this project.

I notice "REQUEST_URI" also includes GET variables, which I don't need.

Comment: Full list of elements (with terse descriptions) in `$_SERVER` can be found in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Thanks. The document didn't really give a lot of info about the vars. It did mention URL rewriting briefly, but didn't fully address my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the actual file being requested then you should use `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (absolute filesystem path) or `SCRIPT_NAME` (root-relative filesystem path) or ...the magic constant `__FILE__` for the current script being executed (but this isn't necessarily the file being requested by the user).

> Would/Could any of these array members not refer to the actual file requested via URL?

Yes.

Whilst `PHP_SELF` refers to the requested file, it can also include *additional pathname information* (`PATH_INFO`) from the URL. eg. `/file.php/foo/bar`.

`REQUEST_URI` is the URL being requested, so this can be completely different. Only when the requested URL directly maps to a filesystem path do these look similar. For example, if the URL `/foo` *internally rewrites* to `/file.php` then `REQUEST_URI` holds `/foo`, not `/file.php`.